# Spring Boot @Async NullPointerException error

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Service
public class Listener {
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> bars;

    public Listener() {
        bars = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    @Async
    public void addBars(CountDownLatch counter) {
        bars.put("hello", "world");
        counter.countDown();
    }
}

@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    Listener listener;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String trial() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch counter = new CountDownLatch(1);
        listener.addBars(counter);
        counter.await();
        return listener.bars.get("hello");
    }
}
```

Why does this throw `NullPointerException` error (when I directly access `bars`), but when I access it via `getBars()` method (i.e., changing it from `listener.bars.get("hello");` to `listener.getBars().get("hello");`, it runs successfully?

Comment: Because the listener is autowired (injected) by Spring. It is a proxy and not an instance of the class. Only the public methods are exposed not the fields.

Comment: But it works when I change it back to a synchronous method (removing the @Async and CountDownLatch).